# How if(x & y) condition works in c++

Tags: c++

In c++ what is the difference between `if(x & 5)` and `if(x <= 5)`? 
I have put `x=4` and in both of cases the output is same.

Comment: I gotta tell you, that's a very random pair of operators to be comparing.

Comment: Have you tried with inputs other than `x=4`?

Comment: What's the difference between 4+3 and 9-2?

Comment: Funny: `if(true)` gives the same output ...

Comment: `2+2` gives the same result as `2*2`, so is addition the same as multiplication?

Answer (score 15):

With `x & 5` you are making a **bitwise and** operation (it is not a **logical and**). Since:

```
4 = 0b0100 AND
5 = 0b0101 =
---------------
4 = 0b0100 != 0
```

the result of the condition is `true`. That 4 is less or equal of 5 (`4 <= 5`) is again `true`.
**But you are not testing the same condition**, you are only comparing two operations that both return `true`. It is only by chance that both return true.

Don't worry: this is a mistake that many people that just started programming make. Please check out the differences between [bitwise operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) and [logical connectives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective).

Comment: This answer is an example of why I don't advocate nuking bad questions. Sometimes you find a diamond in a lump of coal.

Comment: I don't think it is actually a too bad question. By teaching programming in a mechanical engineering course, this is a mistake that I have seen often: many students are not used to the concept of bit representation, and don't know that exist the concept of bitwise operation.

Comment: The subject may make a good question (and answer), but I think this one in particular was very badly asked.

Comment: Please be my guest and edit. You deserve the points :)

Comment: Yes, you are right about the "badly asked"... by the way thanks for the very nice comment @StoryTeller.

Comment: No points for edits after the first few thousand rep, but if we're not going to collide...

Comment: @user4581301 Ouch... what a rep.. thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 1):

The `&` operator on integer is bit by bit.

`4` is `00000000 00000000 00000000 00000100`

`5` is `00000000 00000000 00000000 00000101`

`4 & 5` is `00000000 00000000 00000000 00000100` (`and` operation)

So `4 & 5 = 4`.

And if you convert an integer to boolean all numbers other than `0` is evaluated to `true`.

Comment: the answer you are giving **is right**, but keep in mind that a variable it is not "converted" to a boolean, but it is stored in memory through a base 2 number (for example `4 = 0b100`) and may be represented in other ways. You can enter `int a = 0b100;` and the compiler will not complain.

Comment: @MatteoRagni The wording looks ok to me. The standard uses a similar wording too: *"[stmt.select] 4 ... The value of a condition that is an expression is the value of the
expression, contextually converted to bool ..."*.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat very good catch. Than, I think nobody should care about my previous comment. Thank you for sharing!